# jQuery appending thumbnail images returning "undefined"

Tags: jquery

I need a second set of eyes on this one here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    thumbnails = ['images/image1.png', 'images/image2.png', 'images/image3.png', 'images/image4.png', 'images/image5.png', 'images/image6.png', 'images/image7.png', 'images/image8.png']
    $('#images img').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newImage = $('<img src="' + thumbnails.filename + '"/>');
        var dragdiv = $('<div class="draggable">' + newImage.value + '</div>');
        $('#imageBox').append(dragdiv);
        $('.draggable').draggable({
        scroll: false,
        containment: '#imageBox'
        });
        $('.draggable img').resizable({
        handles: "all"
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var newImage = '<img src="' + thumbnails.filename + '"/>';
var dragdiv  = '<div class="draggable">' + newImage.value + '</div>';
```

instead of

```
var newImage = $('<img src="' + thumbnails.filename + '"/>');
var dragdiv  = $('<div class="draggable">' + newImage.value + '</div>');
```

<kbd>**NEW EDIT**</kbd> : I hope this is what you were looking for

```
$(function()
{
$('#images img').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

 var newImage = '<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"/>';
 var dragdiv  = '<div class="draggable">' + newImage + '</div>';

    $('#imageBox').append(dragdiv);
    $('.draggable').draggable
        ({
            scroll: false,
            containment: '#imageBox'
    });

    $('.draggable img').resizable({
            handles: "all"
    });
}); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I put it in, but it still shows "undefined".

Comment: what is filename here ?? its giving errror

Comment: For some reason jsfiddle is not working, but here is a url: http://theimpactgroup-us.com/dragtest/prototype6.html

Comment: @Matthias I edited my answer , please have a look now !This is what you were looking for?